# How to add a utc offset to a substring c#

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

I have a method that returns a new model as follows

```
return new Model
{          
    markets = response.markets
};
```

the markets object looks as follows:

```
markets: "B234851T001 - 23/08/04 11:31, B234961T002 - 23/08/04 03:43"
```

i need to add a UTC offset +2 to each of the dateTime. so that it would look as follows

```
markets: "B234851T001 - 23/08/04 13:31, B234961T002 - 23/08/04 05:43"
```

usually if the market object wasn't a string and just a single datetime object i would do something as follows:

```
markets.AddHours(2)
```

But i am not sure how to do this with multiple datetimes in a string to achieve the desired mentioned output?
Note: i can not edit the string before its been accessed by the model

Comment: Can't you do it before it's not yet a string but a `DateTime`?

Comment: @PawełŁukasik no i cant, its been sent from another api

Comment: You presumably do something with the markets data?  Then you presumably also have a parser for the markets strings that knows how to interpret the data in it and at best creates a usable class for that? Then the solution is to parse the string, change the parsed data accordingly and then recreate the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Split the string
2. parse the DateTimes
3. adjust them
4. rebuild the string with the corrected DateTimes

This works:

```
var startstring = "B234851T001 - 23/08/04 11:31, B234961T002 - 23/08/04 03:43";

var splitStrings = startstring.Split(',');
var dateStrings = splitStrings.Select(x => x.Substring(x.IndexOf("-") + 2));

var adjustedDateTimes = dateStrings.Select(x => DateTime.Parse(x).AddHours(2)).ToList();
var startOfStrings = splitStrings.Select(x => x.Substring(0, x.IndexOf("-"))).ToList();

var result = startOfStrings[0] + "- " + adjustedDateTimes[0].ToString(@"yy/MM/dd HH:mm");
for (var i = 1; i < startOfStrings.Count(); i++)
{
    result += ", " + startOfStrings[i] + "- " + adjustedDateTimes[i].ToString(@"yy/MM/dd HH:mm");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the structure is always the same, I'd do this:

```
var markets = "B234851T001 - 23/08/04 11:31, B234961T002 - 23/08/04 03:43";

string AddUtc2(string input) =>
    DateTime
        .ParseExact(input, @"yy/MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
        .AddHours(2.0)
        .ToString(@"yy/MM/dd HH:mm");


var parts = markets.Split(new[] { " - ", ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var output = $"{parts[0]} - {AddUtc2(parts[1])}, {parts[2]} - {AddUtc2(parts[3])}";
```

That produces `B234851T001 - 23/08/04 13:31, B234961T002 - 23/08/04 05:43`.